# using shell script,convert decimal format to four octets format

Tags: shell

I want to convert decimal format number to four octets format number.for example decimal number xxxxxxxxxxxxx is convert in to four octets number yy.yy.yy.yyy(like ip address format).How to convert this using shell script.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ N=6473673
$ echo "obase=2; $N" | bc | sed ":r /.\{32\}$/ { s:........:&;:g ; /^/ s::ibase=2;obase=10000;:; q } ; /^/ s::0:; tr " | bc | sed 'H ; $ {x;s:\n::; s:\n:.:g;q} ;d'
0.62.C7.C9
$
```

I converted to HEX. If you want to convert to other base, just tell me to modify the calls.

Comment: holy cow!  that wastes, er, uses a lot of processes!  If you're going to use `bc` you should be able to do it all in one process.  `bc` is at least as usable as AWK for scripting a complete solution inside one invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming your dotted octet format really does mean you want the decimal numbers for each 8-bit portion of a, say, 32-bit integer, then it's not really that hard to do.  Just think a bit about various representations of the number, i.e. different bases with which you can express the same value, and what exactly an *octet* is, and then think about how you could make such transformations in a shell script.

First you could convert the integer from decimal to hex.

Then you break apart the hex value into two-character groups, and convert each of them back to decimal.

Finally you would assemble your string with the connecting dots.

The `bc` program is handy at doing the base conversions, but even easier might be the `printf` command (which might even be built into your shell).  Modern shells also support the expansion modifiers `%`, `%%`, `#`, and `##` that allow you to express patterns such that variable values can be split apart in controlled ways.

So, if we put that all together we have:

```
hx=$(printf '%08x\n' $integer)
hx1=${hx#??????}
tm=${hx%??}
hx2=${tm#????}
tm=${tm%??}
hx3=${tm#??}
hx4=${tm%??}
printf '%d.%d.%d.%d\n' 0x$hx4 0x$hx3 0x$hx2 0x$hx1
```

You could write something much the same in AWK, etc., and then just call it from the shell, but what I've shown is pure `sh` (especially if `printf` is built-in).  AWK might be more efficient if you've got a long list of values to transform (especially if `printf` is *not* built-in).